# Having trouble building a game (camera)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've been having some troubles building a game.
Every time I run the application the console renders the image on the wrong site of the phone. Meaning that the walls, the ball and the force should be render vertical. However, it is rendered horizontal (on the phone landscape). Please help fix this issue.
Thanks a lot.

```
package com.luca.tuninga;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.*;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {


public static float APP_FPS = 60f;
public static int V_WIDTH = 480;
public static int V_HEIGHT = 640;


Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;
World world;
Body ballBody;

OrthographicCamera camera;

float cameraMaxY;

@Override
public void create() {
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.8f), false);
    b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();


    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, V_WIDTH, V_HEIGHT);
    cameraMaxY = camera.position.y;


    ballBody = createBall();
    createWalls();
}

private void update() {
    world.step(1f / APP_FPS, 6, 2);

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        ballBody.setLinearVelocity(0, MathUtils.clamp(ballBody.getLinearVelocity().y, 0, 3));
        ballBody.applyForceToCenter(new Vector2(0, 650f), false);
    }

    if (ballBody.getPosition().y * 32 > cameraMaxY) {
        camera.translate(0, (ballBody.getPosition().y * 32) - cameraMaxY);
        camera.update();

        cameraMaxY = camera.position.y;
    }
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.25f, .25f, .25f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    update();

    b2dr.render(world, camera.combined.cpy().scl(32f));
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    world.dispose();
}

private Body createBall() {
    Body body;
    BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
    def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    def.fixedRotation = true;
    def.position.set(camera.position.x/ 32 + .5f, camera.position.y/ 32);
    def.gravityScale = 3;
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(.5f);

    body = world.createBody(def);
    body.createFixture(shape, 1.0f);
    return body;

}

private void createWalls() {
    Body body;
    BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
    def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    def.fixedRotation = true;

    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(1, 200 / 32);
    for(int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++) {
        def.position.set(1.01f, i * (200 / 32));
        body = world.createBody(def);
        body.createFixture(shape, 1.0f);

        def.position.set(V_WIDTH / 32 - 1, i * (200 / 32));
        body = world.createBody(def);
        body.createFixture(shape, 1.0f);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question right, but on the phone (iOS and Android) you need to assign the orientation manually. Find orientation in AndroidManifest.xml and assign it to landscape.

Example:

```
<activity
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind to call `camera.update();` directly after calling other methods on it. Ideally update the camera on every frame.